# gwt servlet getRessourceAsStream always returns null

Tags: java, servlets, gwt

I have this peace of code to load a text file inside of a `servlet`:

```
String lFileName = mServletContext.getRealPath(mFile);
InputStream lInputStream = mServletContext.getResourceAsStream(lFileName);
InputStream lInputStream2 = mServletContext.getResourceAsStream(mFile);
```

Both `InputStream's` are `null`. I have absolutly no idear why.

The value of `mFile` is `"file.txt"`.
The value of `lFile` is `"C:\development\workspace\MyGwtApp\war\file.txt"`.

if I navigate with my explorer to that directory the file `file.txt` is in it...!

I test my gwt application with the `super dev mode`.
Compile the gwt app runs without problems.

Do you see the problem?

Comment: Maybe some problem with file permissions allowing you to access the file in explorer but not allowing your web server to access it?

Comment: my eclipse runs with admin rights

Comment: The file path has to be relative to your servlet context, i.e. "/file.txt".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

getResourceAsStream definition

> Finds a resource with a given name. The rules for searching resources associated with a given class are implemented by the defining class loader of the class. This method delegates to this object's class loader.

This means that you can read mFile if it exists in your classpath like under WEB-INF/classes. So place your file in your src directory where your java classes exists and look if the file comes to the classes directory and just use its name to get it as resource. Example: filename = "file.txt"

Comment: We have got a downvoter thats a good sign, someone gives response :)

Comment: nearly correct. It is not necesarry to put the file in the classes directory. But in my case it was necessary to put it in the WEB-INF directory. I put it in the war directory. Nevertheless you give me a good hint.